# Why does my outlook textboxes look like this

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

My outlook updated and now I just have lines for textboxes instead of a full textbox how do I fix this ? I am working on a surface laptop which has a touch screen if it makes a difference

[image: Outlook new mail]

Comment: They probably just changed visual style to a cleaner, minimalist one. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: has anyone else seen this then ? .... I don't like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the detailed version of Outlook?
From newer builds of Office 365, Microsoft have a new feature: "Coming Soon". The redesign is aimed at cleaning up the Outlook interface, bringing in flatter elements, and introducing more intelligent features.

We can find this option in the upper left corner of Outlook window.

[image]

If it is enabled, you will see the new simplified UI. If you don't like it, you can turn off this option and restart Outlook. You will revert to original dialog.

Reference: https://content.sentrian.com.au/blog/outlook-redesign-revealed-coming-soon